# What's the measure of the segment $BD$ in the figure below?

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, plane-geometry

For reference: The angle $B$ of a triangle $ABC$ measures $120^o$. On $AB$, $BC$ and $AC$ points $M$ are marked; $N$ and $L$ respectively. The circumscribed circles to the triangles $AML$ and $LNC$ intersect in $P$.
If $BM = 4, BN = 2$ and $MBP=60^o$. Calculate $BP$ (Answer:$6$)

My progress:

[image]

Just use CHADU's theorem..

$\therefore BP = BM + BN\\
\boxed{BP = 2 + 4 = 6}$

t remains to be demonstrated that the triangle MNP is equilateral to use the theorem (the geogebra confirms) but I couldn't...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The angles subtended by segment $ML$ at point $A$ and at point $P$ are equal. The angles subtended by segment $NL$ at point $C$ and at point $P$ are equal.

So show that $\angle MPN = \angle A + \angle C = 60^0$

Then $BMPN$ is cyclic. So $\angle MNP = \angle MBP = 60^0$.

So $\triangle MNP$ is equilateral.

You can also apply Ptolemy's theorem in quadrilateral $BMPN$ to find $BP$.

Comment: Yes but anyway you need to demonstrate that the quadrilateral is cyclic... and Chadu's theorem is simpler than Ptolemy..Thanks for help

Comment: @petaarantes Yes I agree but my point is about what Ptolemy's Theorem yields for an equilateral triangle. See equilateral triangle section in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ptolemy%27s_theorem. I never knew this as Chadu's theorem. Do you have any link on Chadu's theorem?

Comment: Chadu's Theorem: In every quadrilateral inscribed in a circumference or inscribable, such that three vertices are the vertices of an equilateral triangle, then the distance from the fourth furthest vertex is equal to the sum of the distances from this to the other two vertices of the equilateral triangle.    I couldn't find a match in English...it's a theorem used in South America (Peru, Brazil...)...I've only seen it in books

Comment: I think that's what they called this variation of Ptolemy's theorem for the equilateral triangle you mentioned.

Answer (score 2):

This is a straightforward application of [Miquel's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miquel%27s_theorem) :

> Choose three arbitrary points $M,N,L$ on sides $AB,BC,CA$ of $\triangle ABC$. Then circumcircles of $\triangle$s $AML$, $BMN$ and $CNL$ intersect in a single point (known as Miquel point).

Since circumcircles of $\triangle$s $AML, CNL$ intersect in $P$, circumcircle of $\triangle BMN$ also passes through $P$. Changing the view slightly, $B$ lies on circumcircle of $\triangle MNP$. With some easy angle chasing, $\triangle MNP$ can be shown to be equilateral.

Now applying your mentioned theorem, or as a corollary of Ptolemy's theorem, it follows that
$$BP=BM+BN=6$$

Comment: Thanks for help and grateful for the presentation of the theorem